# How can I access my Rails backend API information in my Ember client side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ember.js

I'm a beginner at coding and I'm working on [this tutorial](http://mentalized.net/journal/2014/06/01/ember_on_rails_02/) right now and I'm having a bit of trouble. I would really appreciate some help!

Here's my problem: I'm using an external API in my Rails backend. I'm not using a model. But the tutorial is asking me to access a model in this section when I want to access my API information from my Rails class.

This is what they want me to do:

```
Library.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
   return this.get('store').find('book');
  }
 });
```

How can I change that code to access my API? I'm using HTTP party.

Here's a bit of what my activities controller looks like:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  include HTTParty
  base_uri ''   # took this out
  def index
    render json: self.class.get("")  # took out my link with API key here
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

that ember code looks correct. I think part of the confusion is that Ember has its own models which are not the same as rails models.

The tutorial asks you to curl your books endpoint. Have you verified you can do that and are getting back an JSON object representing your books?

If you're getting back valid JSON and ember is set up to use the ActiveModelAdapter (like the tutorial says ember-rails automatically does for you) then this.store.find('book') in the model route should make a GET request to your rails API book endpoint. You can perform a network trace in chrome developer tools to verify this.

What evidence do you have that this is not working?

Comment: I think I'm confused on how to make the request.. Because right now I am not trying to access a model (if I am correct), I am trying to access my Ruby controller that is using HTTParty and has my external API calls..  I don't know how I can call my API in Ember.js..     the Ember.route.extend part is most confusing to me.. It wants me to use the model:function code, but I am not trying to access a model but the information from my API from my controller and the httparty thing. Thank you SO MUCH for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you again.. I have been stuck on this for like a week. I really want to be able to use HTTParty and access my API information but I have no idea how..

Comment: Assuming you followed the tutorial and have everything else set up Ember should automatically make the request to your rails controller ( which in turn will hit your API ) when you load the Books route (aka visit the url for that route in a web browser). 

I suggest you read and go through the tutorials at emberjs.com for a deeper understanding of the basics of ember and then slowly work in the integration with an api.

Comment: Oh, and when you visit a route in ember, the code in the 'model hook' will automatically get executed. The return value will act as the model for your ember controllers, templates, etc associated with that route. If this doesn't make much sense, you may want to pick up some books on MVC patterns (model, view controller) or go through some of the books here to understand MVCs in the context of Ember: http://emberwatch.com/books.html